# How to simply display table rows in calender format with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a table that holds 'reservations'. So the structure is simple and looks like this.

Reservations:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| ResID | CarID | UserID | startTime | startDate | endTime | endDate  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1   |   4   |    4   | 13:00:00  |2013-04-21 |13:00:00 |2013-04-29|
```

These are updated and added by users in the front end as well as by admin. SO there is no need for users to be able to update the dates via the calender.

But I would like a simple way to display these dates in a calender format. I have looked at a few open source solutions like PHP Calender and a few JQuery solutions but ideally all I want is a simple interface to show these reservations in calender format, so that I can then build on this.

I have also found a few scripts on line, where the PHP written seems somewhat dated.

So really I am just looking for a starting point to loop through enteries from my database table, as I do with normal tables.

Can anyone suggest the simplest way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are alright with using jQuery I would suggest you use http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ .
Its really easy to add events to this calendar interface and it looks really clean.  You can disable most of the functions like dragging events since it seems like you will not need them.